# Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after {_timeout} ms - (reason: {_error}). Ionic Error

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_121 '"C:\Program
>   Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.14.1\bin\gradle"' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file. (node:7436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with
>   exit code 1 (node:7436) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.

Comment: You have to provide more info and clarify more your question.

Comment: When i select Run Android on device and run ionic3 app  then show this error in VS code also shows "Cannot connect to runtime process,time out after 10000ms -(cannot connect to target : read ECONNREST) " @onetwo12